# Cannot derive implicit instance of type class using shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I want to derive instances of type classes from unary case classes. But when i try to implicitly derive it i always get an error message. If i derive it explicitly using implicit method - it works. I'm not sure, but maybe the reason is that i missed some implicit types in my function

```
import shapeless._

import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

sealed trait Foo[A] {
  def hello(): Unit
}

object Foo {
  def apply[A](implicit foo: Foo[A]): foo.type = foo

  def instance[A](implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): Foo[A] = new Foo[A] {
    override def hello(): Unit = println(s"Hello from ${tag.runtimeClass.getName}")
  }
}

trait Instances extends LowestPriority {
  implicit val intHelloInstance: Foo[Int] = Foo.instance[Int]
}

trait LowestPriority {
  implicit def derive[A: TypeTag, L <: HList, H](
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, L],
    H: Lazy[Foo[H]],
    isUnary: (H :: HNil) =:= L
  ): Foo[A] =
    new Foo[A] {
      override def hello(): Unit = {
        print(s"Derived: ")
        H.value.hello()
      }
    }
}

object T extends Instances {

  case class A(a: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    intHelloInstance.hello()
//    val a: Foo[A] = derive[A, Int :: HNil, Int] // this works
//    a.hello()
    Foo[A].hello() // error
  }
}
```

From logs:

> Information:(45, 8) shapeless.this.Generic.materialize is not a valid
>   implicit value for shapeless.Generic.Aux[H,L] because:
>   hasMatchingSymbol reported error: H is not a case class, case
>   class-like, a sealed trait or Unit
>       Foo[A].hello()

How can i fix it?

Comment: What is a 'unary' case class?

Comment: It is a case class with only 1 parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cases when behavior depends on... the order of implicits to resolve.

If you modify signature to:

```
  implicit def derive[A, L <: HList, H](
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, L],
    isUnary: (H :: HNil) =:= L, // swapped
    H: Lazy[Foo[H]]             // with this
  ): Foo[A] = ...
```

compiler will:

- try to find some `HList` `L` that could be paired with `A`
- then prove that `L` equal to some `H :: HNil` figuring out `H` in the process
- finally using that `H` to fetch `Lazy[Foo[H]]`

and you will successfully compile `Foo[A].hello()`.

When these two last argument are swapped to what you have in your question, compiler has to

- assume some `H` (which in our test case most likely WON"T be Int)
- then forcefully try to adjust `L` to match it
- then go back to `Generic` which now is forced to prove that `A` is representable by some `H :: HNil` where `H` is most likely not `Int` and failing to do it but with a misguiding error information

This is one of these cases that shows that shapeless based derivation is sometimes tricky, and also here it shows that shapeless authors assumed in macros that the most likely cause of macro expansion failure is that `A` was not case class, while as we just saw it might be also compiler forcing some impossible proof because type inference got things wrong because we resolved them in wrong order.

Comment: Thank you! It helped!
But can you explain if possible this case (from doobie): https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/scala/doobie/util/get.scala#L198 

Mostly i use this sample as basis, but in case of doobie, it seems as a workable code without the reordering of implicits

Comment: I believe it works because there is `C: IsHCons.Aux[L, H, T]` which makes Scala resolve `H` correctly before moving on to other implicits and type parameters. Basing on example that you provided, if you remove it, compilation would fail.

Comment: Hm, it's interesting. Thank you again, now i have some insight why code may fails